# git reset or rebase - remove commits from past

Tags: git, github, version-control, reset, rebase

I am trying to get rid of commits but not sure how to do it. I read a lot about git reset and git rebase but still don't get it. Most people needed to delete/revert last commit and It is not I am trying to do.

To better understand what I want to do: I was working on branch X and then wanted to merge it to master. But I realized that on 5th commit I added much code that was not mine (it was framework). It makes reviewing changes between X and master very hard. So I checkout that 5th commit as new branch Y and want to get rid of 4 previous commits and then merge it to master. This way when create pull request with branch X hopefully the 5th commit will not be seen as changes, am I right here? Assuming yes, I still need to remove those 4 commits leaving no history to get no merge conflicts.

So when type git log on branch Y I get something like this:

```
git log 
commit: A1
commit: A2 
commit: A3
commit: A4
commit: A5
```

How do I remove commits A2-A5 leaving no trace of them? Is what I am trying to makes sense?

Comment: You can `git squash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to create `branchY` only with commit `A1`, and then merge it into `master` before the pull request merging branch into master completed. You can use below way:

Assume the original branch structure looks like below graph, and you created pull request when `branchX` was point to `A1`, `master` branch was point to `E`.

```
A---B---C---D---E                master
         \
          A5---A4---A3---A2---A1 branchX
```

Then find the parent commit which `branchX` was created (as commit `C` in the graph). So you can create `branchY` from commit `C` and then cherry-pick the 5th commit (`A1`) on it:

```
git checkout -b branchY <commit id for C>
git cherry-pick <commit id for A1>
```

Then the commit history will look like:

```
            A1'                    branchY
          /
 A---B---C---D---E                 master
          \
            A5---A4---A3---A2---A1 branchX
```

Finally you can merge `branchY` into `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge branchY
git push origin master
```

The merge commit on `master` branch as `F` in below graph:

```
           __ A1'___               branchY
          /         \
 A---B---C---D---E---F             master
          \
            A5---A4---A3---A2---A1 branchX
```

Now your pull request merging `branchX` into `master` branch will compare changes between version `F` and `A1` (the framework changes will not be compared).

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD~N
```

where N is the number of commit you want to reset. After this operation you'll find in your working directory file you have in commit A1 but without your commits.

If you `add .` and then `git commit` you have a new commit and old N commit will be lost.

I prefer use rebase. When I work on new features, I always open new branch. I commit each 5/6 minutes. When I complete the task, if my branch must be merged to `master` branch I run the command

```
git rebase - i master
```

After that, I squash all commit but the first. Finally, I have only one commit. I hope this help you.